# How to make parent li get pushed down by child li (mobile navigation)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Many thanks in advance,

i'm stuck with mobile navigation. I have main nav with some subnavigation that is hidden. 
Clicking on the parent li opens subnav, but subnav hides all other parents li that is underneath.

How can I make that child li "squeeze in" between parent ul by pushing parent li downward?

```js
$(".main-nav").find("li").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".subnav").toggle();
});
```

```css
.main-nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.subnav {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>Nav 1</li>
  <li>Nav 2</li>
  <li> Nav 3
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav 1</li>
      <li>Subnav 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Nav 4
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav 1</li>
      <li>Subnav 2</li>
      <li>Subnav 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Nav 5</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `.subnav` `position` to `relative`:

```js
$(".main-nav").find("li").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".subnav").toggle();
});
```

```css
.main-nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.subnav {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>Nav 1</li>
  <li>Nav 2</li>
  <li> Nav 3
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav 1</li>
      <li>Subnav 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Nav 4
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav 1</li>
      <li>Subnav 2</li>
      <li>Subnav 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Nav 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm